# where is asn1rt_ber_bin module?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

When testing "rabbitmq's ldap" (version 3.4.2), the rabbitmq's log shows error as follows:

But in erlang's doc, no such "asn1rt_ber_bin" module. What's the problem here ?

```
=INFO REPORT==== 31-Dec-2014::13:56:31 ===
    LDAP bind error: cn=admin,dc=xxx,dc=xxx {'EXIT',
                                                 {undef,
                                                  [{asn1rt_ber_bin,
                                                    decode_tag,
                                                    [<<48,12,2,1,1,97,7,10,1,
                                                       0,4,0,4,0>>],
                                                    []},
                                                   {eldap,check_tag,1,
                                                    [{file,
                                                      "eldap-wrapper/eldap-git/src/eldap.erl"},
                                                     {line,683}]},
                                                   {eldap,recv_response,2,
                                                    [{file,
                                                      "eldap-wrapper/eldap-git/src/eldap.erl"},
                                                     {line,670}]},
                                                   {eldap,exec_simple_bind,1,
                                                    [{file,
                                                      "eldap-wrapper/eldap-git/src/eldap.erl"},
                                                     {line,451}]},
                                                   {eldap,do_the_simple_bind,
                                                    3,
                                                    [{file,
                                                      "eldap-wrapper/eldap-git/src/eldap.erl"},
                                                     {line,438}]},
                                                   {eldap,loop,2,
                                                    [{file,
                                                      "eldap-wrapper/eldap-git/src/eldap.erl"},
                                                     {line,397}]}]}}
```

The related code is as follows:

```
%%% Sanity check of received packet
check_tag(Data) ->
    case asn1rt_ber_bin:decode_tag(b2l(Data)) of
    {_Tag, Data1, _Rb} ->
        case asn1rt_ber_bin:decode_length(b2l(Data1)) of
        {{_Len, _Data2}, _Rb2} -> ok;
        _ -> throw({error,decoded_tag_length})
        end;
    _ -> throw({error,decoded_tag})
    end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been removed since R15. You can use the R14 Erlang release, or follow the information given in the readme of the R15:

> OTP-9419  The linked-in driver used for ber decode and per encode has
>           been replaced with nifs. To enable the usage of nifs pass the
>           nif option to erlc or asn1rt:compile when compiling. If you
>           previously used the linked-in driver, you have to recompile
>           your ASN1 modules with the current version of asn1
>           application as the linked-in driver modules have been
>           removed.